# Stacked bar chart using google charts api

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have successfully made a google bar chart showing based on values from mysql. Now i want to make it **stacked chart**.

I have seen many examples and came through the fact that this effect is generated using the chart paramaeters like **chco, cht, chd** etc alongwith the charts api url, i.e., something like this:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World
```

I was trying to make the chart using the basic method to make a bar chart using mysql, that is fetching data from mysql and encoding it in json and sending the same to chart script, like:

**Chart Code:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var json = $.ajax({
            url: 'get_json_rank.php', // make this url point to the data file
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
        var options = {
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            is3D: 'true',
            width: 500,
            height: 320,
            colors:['#4D515D'],
            hAxis: {
                textPosition:'none',
                title: "Restaurants"},
            vAxis: {
                title: "Business Growth",
                }
        };
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        //do not forget to check ur div ID
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('rank_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        setInterval(drawChart, 500 );
    }
</script>
```

I want to add the following parameters in the chart in which the **php variables must be included** as they represent the men and women ratio in the bar:

```
        cht='bhs',
        chco='4D89F9','C6D9FD'
        chd='t:'+ <?php echo $a; ?> +'|'+ <?php echo $b;?>,
        chds='0,160'
```

Now can somebody let me know how to turn this simple bar graph into stacked. Any help wud be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get stacked bar chart using option:

```
isStacked: true
```

`is3D: 'true'` is option used for pie chart.

Options `chco, cht, chd...` are for image charts which are deprecated. See google [Image charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params)